# Python 2.5 version of this method

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have the below function running fine on python 2.6, but appengine's production environment is 2.5 and it blows up on:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Mapping'

Does anyone have a solution for 2.5?

Thanks

Chris

```
import types, collections

class AttrDict(dict):
    '''AttrDict - dict with JS-like key=attr access'''
    def __init__(self, *argz, **kwz):
        if len(argz) == 1 and not kwz and isinstance(argz[0], types.StringTypes):
            super(AttrDict, self).__init__(open(argz[0]))
        else:
            super(AttrDict, self).__init__(*argz, **kwz)
            for k,v in self.iteritems(): setattr(self, k, v) # re-construct all values via factory

    def __val_factory(self, val):
        return AttrDict(val) if isinstance(val, collections.Mapping) else val

    def __getattr__(self, k):
        return super(AttrDict, self).__getitem__(k)
        __getitem__ = __getattr__

    def __setattr__(self, k, v):
        return super(AttrDict, self).__setitem__(k, self.__val_factory(v))
        __setitem__ = __setattr__
```

Comment: Try to stop using `isinstance`!

Comment: Do you absolutely have to force all dictionaries to be AttrDicts when you set them as attributes? That's a bit magical/implicit. Maybe the poor dicts doesn't want to be AttrDicts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace

```
isinstance(val, collections.Mapping)
```

with

```
isinstance(val, dict)
```

Comment: Or get rid of `isinstance` calls completely, since they are the enemy of duck typing.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov and what do you suggest instead?

Answer (score 1):

The function will never get a parameter that is an instance of `Mapping` because that class is not in python 2.5.  Simply replace that line with `return val`.

This is assuming none of your other code uses `Mapping` or a subclass thereof.  If you're actually using it, you'll have to come up with a replacement.